# How is "direct search" used, in general, to solve a system of nonlinear equations?

Tags: optimization, algorithms, nonlinear-optimization

I'm interested in using direct search ([see](https://www.mathworks.com/help/gads/what-is-direct-search.html)) to solve *systems* of nonlinear equations. Unfortunately, however, there isn't much detailed information out there on the direct search family of algorithms. So, I'm interested... how, precisely, are direct search algorithms used to solve nonlinear system in practice? I know that it *can* and *has* been done. I also know other methods are available (Newton-Raphson, etc). I'm simply interested in this method, which does not require differentiation.

---

> **From MathWorks:**
>
> Direct search is a method for solving optimization problems that does
> not require any information about the gradient of the objective
> function. Unlike more traditional methods... the direct search algorithm uses a set of points around the current point, looking for one where the value of the objective function is lower than the value at the current point. You can use direct search to solve problems for which the objective function is not differentiable, or is not even continuous.

Comment: The simplest version is to imagine an evenly spaced grid of points in space, try every single point in the grid, and see which one comes closest to satisfying your system of equations.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for the worst possible way of solving the problem, you have found it. But if you insist:

For each nonlinear equation, form the left-hand side minus right hand side. Then square each of these. Then sum these over all the equations. This will be the objective function for an unconstrained nonlinear least squares (optimization) problem. Then apply MATLAB's Direct Search algorithm to this optimization problem.

If the algorithm finds a point having objective value equal zero, that point is a solution of the original system of nonlinear equations. If it finds a point having objective function value almost zero, that point is "almost" a solution of the original system of nonlinear equations, and you will have to judge whether it is close enough to being a solution to suit your purposes.

Comment: Thanks! I understand that there exist better alternatives, I was simply interested in how the algorithm could work without using differentiation, out of curiosity. Sounds like its basically in the same spirit as brute force.

Comment: Basically, the algorithm evaluates the objective function at a bunch of points, and picks the best one. Brute force, hope for the best, whatever you want to call it. I'm not a big fan.

Comment: It is interesting to me that the only "direct" approach to nonlinear equation solving (IOW root finding) seems to be bisection (for a single equation) - the only alternative "methods" I am aware of seem to be based on "shoe-horning" optimization methods (hence the squaring, as you have pointed out).  Is there a fundamental mathematical reason for this?